# Was that Julie Newmar on Thriller's S01E28?

Tags: thriller-tv

In the [Thriller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thriller_%28U.S._TV_series%29) episode, *[Yours Truly, Jack the Ripper](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0723128/)* (S01E28, 11 Apr. 1961), was that Julie Newmar as one of the victims? I looked up Pamela Curran and Jill Livesey and they don't look like her, but she is not mentioned in the credits.

Comment: When is this victim shown in the episode?  ([Episode on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CtILSL5bDsY))

Comment: This seems easily answerable by taking a look at IMDB or some similar source...

Comment: It actually took following a chain of sites, as the actress in question is not listed as a victim and none of the actresses has a photo in imdb.

Answer (score 1):

Pamela Curran in the episode:

[image]

Nancy Valentine in the episode:

[image]

Nancy Valentine is not listed as a victim on imdb, but she does become one.

And this is Julie Newmar from the same era. She looks similar, but not the same (she did not always wear her eyebrows that arched, and she was not always blond):

[image]